# How to invoke ajax, so that it should refresh the table and update the column

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

In my application,i have four columns in my datatable.Initially, except second column all the other columns displays the value. The second column values should be displayed by automatic refresh.
like
Initially table looks like

```
ID type Name Color 
1       Benz White 
2       Maruti Grey 
3       Renault orange 
4       VW pink
```

After automatic refresh(Using AJAX) it should display like

```
ID type Name Color 
1  2012 Benz White 
2  2013 Maruti Grey 
3  2014 Renault orange 
4  2015 VW pink
```

I have implement this in jsf using ajax.
can any one help me out in this.

Comment: what happened during your implementation?

Comment: you have to accept answers on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Using [richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) this can be done by the `reRender`attribute of some action components. Depending on the way you want to refresh the table, you could either use:

```
<a4j:commandButton reRender="idOftable" />
```

or

```
<a4j:support reRender="idOfTable" .. />
```

If using JSF 2.0, you can use the following equivallent of `<a4j:support>`:

```
<f:ajax render="idOfTable" />
```

Both `<a4j:support>` and `<f:ajax>` have to be nested in other components and define an `event` attribute, on which they are triggered (onclick, onmousemove, etc).